# Internal Onebox show more than 3 content

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am trying to show content more than 3 for internal provider for onebox on GSA 7.4 version. By default it shows up 3 only. There is a setting "Maximum number of OneBox results per search" is a not working. Is there any other way or may be by editing xml or xslt to show more than 3 content?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!! 
Thanks in Advance!!

Enclsoed please find my code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template name="projects">

    <xsl:variable name="URLReplace">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(title/urlLink,'search','GSASearchResults.aspx')"/>
</xsl:variable>


  <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
  <tr>        
    <td valign="top" width="99%">
      <xsl:for-each select="MODULE_RESULT">
        <font size="-1">
            <a>
              <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="U"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="Title"/> 
            </a>
        </font>
        <br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <nobr>
        <a>
          <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="title/urlLink"/>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="$URLReplace"/>
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="concat('GSASearchResults.aspx',substring-after(//title/urlLink,'search'))"></xsl:value-of>-->
          </xsl:attribute>
          <b>
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="title/urlText"/>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="/GSP/PARAM[@name='q']/@original_value"/>
            Click for More.. <!--<xsl:value-of select="$qurl"/>-->
          </b>
        </a>
      </nobr>
    </td>
  </tr>     
</tbody>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So is this a collection based Onebox?

Comment: Yes, it a collection based onebox. Also, if you know how can I edit q parameter in order to add inmeta in it to show content in one box using that, that would be great too. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you post the XSLT for the onebox from Content Sources > OneBox Modules, it's possible that you have 3 hard coded in there somewhere.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have posted my xslt in my original post. Please find the same. Thank you so much for looking into this. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: If you actually export an existing onebox there is a field containing the collection. You can add any parameter after it, such as requiredfields

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried that and it is working for me. But adding num=10 didn't show me more than 3 content still. It works for other meta tags but not for num. Also, I need to add daterange and that is why I wanted to edit q parameter. Adding &requiredfields= inmeta:daterange:2015-07-27..2016-07-26 didn't work. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @JeremyGarreau Please suggest what is the best way to edit my result to show more than 3 for internal collections and how can I edit q param for daterange. It will be really a great help.Thanks in advance!!